# Error al subir datos a Firebase android permiso denegado estando en publico

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Me salta el siguiente error cuando intento hacer el `setValue();`

```
setValue at / failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
```

Aquí los permisos en mi BBDD:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Y aquí la clase que uso para subir los datos:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editNombre, editApellido,editNia,editEdad;
    Button boton;
    Alumno alumno;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

        editNombre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_nombre);
        editApellido = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_apellido);
        editNia = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_nia);
        editEdad = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_edad);
        boton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.boton);

        alumno = new Alumno();

        boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
                alumno.setNombre(editNombre.getText().toString());
                alumno.setApellido(editApellido.getText().toString());
                alumno.setNia(editNia.getText().toString());
                int edad = Integer.parseInt(editEdad.getText().toString());
                alumno.setEdad(edad);

                myRef.setValue(alumno);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Para poder usar Database de Firebase, necesitas añadir el siguiente permiso al `AndroidManifest`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```